# Maven - Put Dependency Into Other Dependency with Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a Maven POM project test-module3 with two dependencies: Dependency test-module1 and dependency test-module2.

Dependency test-module2 has also test-module1 as dependency with scope set to compile, but it does not have the Maven Shade Plugin or the Maven Assembly Plugin configured.

Now I want to build dependency test-module2 using test-module3. So I configure the Maven Assemby Plugin. That works great. But dependency test-module1 is missing in dependency test-module2.

How can I configure the Maven Assemby Plugin or any other plugin of test-module3 so, that it shades test-module1 into test-module2?

Here are my POMs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-distribution</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <artifactId>test-module1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <artifactId>test-module2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>  
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

distribution.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
      </dependencySet>    
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

POM of test-module1:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-module1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

POM of test-module2:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-module2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-module1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My goal is to put test-module1 in the ZIP folder and test-module2 in the ZIP folder, but test-module2 should also contain test-module1.

Comment: I cannot quite follow you. Why do you want to put a dependency into another one? Is this about using two different versions of B simultaneously?

Comment: Maven doesn't build dependencies, it uses dependencies for your build. Please post your poms.

Comment: I edited the question for clarification.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want test module 1 twice.

Comment: test-module1 is the API for test-module2. So people which want to modify test-module2 can put test-module1 in their local repository and add it as dependency to their pom.xml file with scope set to provided. Then their JAR can run next to test-module2.

Comment: @mines123 do you mean you want test-module1 (the api) as a jar, inside of test-module2 (the implementation) so that you can redistribute the test-module2 jar, and your users will 'conveniently' be able to retrieve the test-module1 jar from inside it?

Comment: No, I want to put test-module1 into test-module2 like I would shade it with the Maven Shade Plugin. And then I want to have test-module1 as a seperate JAR.